# Change pwm voltage using transistor switch

Tags: voltage, transistors, pwm

I have a raspberry pi that generates a 3.3V pwm. I want to bring down the pwm high voltage to 2.5V for my application. So instead of going from 0 to 3.3V, the output pwm should go from 0 to 2.5V while maintaining the same duty cycle and frequency. I found two ways to do this and have attached the circuit diagrams below:

Way 1:

[image]

Way 2:

[image]

I wanted to know if there is any reason to chose one way over the other.
Way 2 seems simpler and more intuitive. The load is a nitinol wire, which needs to be energized using the pwm. Does the load have any effect on the circuit choice? Any general comments that could improve my theoretical understanding of the two circuits and their differences?

Comment: Circuit 2 is what you want. Circuit 1 doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Circuit 2 will invert the sense on the PWM control, but that could be taken account of in the raspberry pi software which generates the PWM. What type of load does the ``nitinol wire`` generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want to use circuit 2.

Circuit 1 hides a property of bipolar transistors:  they can work in reverse.  NPN is NPN whichever N comes first.  Of course, they're optimized with the emitter and collector predefined, so they won't be as efficient in reverse...but with 3.3V available on the base and emitter, I wouldn't be surprised to see something close to 3.3V on the collector as well.

Circuit 2 is much more apt.  You enjoy the full gain of the transistor, and it doesn't necessarily invert, since a high input corresponds to 2.5V across the load (which I assume is strapped between the 2.5V source and the collector).  (Your PWM out should be on the transistor collector, though, as the node you indicated will sit at 2.5V constantly.)

If your load is inductive, you should also put a diode across it to prevent damage to the transistor when it's switched off.